# Ховер эффект при наведение на select option, возможно ли?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как сделать ховер эффект при наведении на option's у select'a без сторонних плагинов на чистом JS либо на Jquery?
p.s без замены на другие теги

Comment: Гугл нашел очень много вариантов. Точного нет. Пробуй все - https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=select+option+hover+change+color&oq=select+option+hover&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.8257j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Какой именно эффект вас интересует?

Comment: Указал в картинке, эффект ховера при наведении на option

Comment: Из ответов на enSO - **This element is rendered by the OS, not HTML. It cannot be styled via CSS.**

Comment: т.е с помощью js это невозможно реализовать?

Comment: "без замены тегов" ни на css, ни на js это не сделать

Comment: Посмотрите здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599975/html-select-box-options-on-hover